# Regex: Extract content between two strings using sed over multiple lines

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, extract

I'd like to extract the content between two strings using *sed* in UNIX. I know that *sed* only works on one line but in my case, I'd like to extract content that stretches over multiple lines.

To give you an idea of the situation, here's a string variable with lines I'd like to extract and lines I'd like to ignore:

```
VAR="Unrelevant
Unrelevant
Title1
Relevant
Relevant
Title2
Unrelevant"
```

Now I'd like to extract the part between "Title1" and "Title2" including "Title1" and save the content into the variable called "RELEVANT". Using *echo* on that variable should be give me this desired output:

```
Title1
Relevant
Relevant
```

My attempt was:

```
RELEVANT=(echo "$VAR" | sed -e 's/.*Title1\(.*\)Title2.*/\1/g'))
```

But this partly worked only when VAR was a one-liner:

```
VAR="Unrelevant Unrelevant Title1 Relevant Relevant Title2 Unrelevant"
```

"Partly", because the output was:

```
 Relevant Relevant
```

... with a space before the first "Relevant", which isn't supposed to be there and without the preceding "Title1".

Well, apart from this, I can't get this working if VAR goes over multiple lines. So my question: How do I get this working for a string which stretches multiple lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a `sed` solution:

```
echo "$var" | sed -n '/^Title1$/,/^Title2$/p' | sed '$d'
```

```
Title1
Relevant
Relevant
```

- `-n` suppresses normal output
- First `sed` command matches text between 2 patterns and prints them using `p` command
- Second `sed` command just skips last line this giving us desired output.

Or with a single `sed`:

```
echo "$var" | sed -n '/^Title1$/,/^Title2$/{/^Title2$/!p;}'
Title1
Relevant
Relevant
```

Comment: I think that's I was looking for!

Could You give me a breakdown of the first solution, though? I can only understand parts of it, but not its entirity.

Again, thank You!

Comment: I have added in my answer.